# How do I properly invoke/manage subsequent subscriptions for my observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Trying to make an observable that pushes to all subscribers, but I've ran into a problem for multiple subscriptions. It was my understanding that subscriber management was automatically handled for me. In the following example, it's my goal to have both 'a' and 'b' be logged.

```
let observer = null as any;
let ob$ = new Observable<any>(ob => {
     //this piece of code will be called twice, over-writing the original 
     observer = ob;
});

ob$.do(() => console.log("a")).subscribe();
ob$.do(() => console.log("b")).subscribe(); //only 'b' is called

observer.next();
observer.complete();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you're using `new Observable()` (this is equivalent to using `Observable.create()`).

Every time you subscribe to `ob$` the callback to `new Observable()` is called where you override `observer`. Then when you call `observer.next()` you're calling `next` only on the second Observer.

In other words `"a"` is never printed because you never call `next` on the Observer that was created inside `new Observable()` when you subscribed to `ob$`.

In general this is not a good way to use  `new Observable()` and for what you're trying to do is better `Subject`.

```
let observer = null as any;
let subject = new Subject();
let ob$ = subject.asObservable();

ob$.do(() => console.log("a")).subscribe();
ob$.do(() => console.log("b")).subscribe(); //only 'b' is called

subject.next();
subject.complete();
```

See live demo: http://jsbin.com/hocagar/4/edit?js,console

This prints:

```
a
b
```